# ejecutar una función cuando cambia un valor con JQuery

Tags: jquery

tengo la siguiente duda , estoy trabajando un input y en teoría cuando este cambie se ejecuta una función que suma otros valores, pero el problema ahora es que hice un tipo de "verificador de códigos" si este código ya está en la lista solo los debe sumarlo al que ya existe lo cual lo hace muy bien pero tango una función que se ejecutaba cuando el valor o la cantidad del producto cambiara solo que antes lo hacía manual y ahora por medio del "verificador de códigos" el valor del input cambia pero para la función es como si esta no hubiera tenido cambios y no la ejecuta les dejo el código ordenado para darme a entender mejor.

**"verificador de códigos"**

```
if(parseInt(codigo1) == parseInt(codigo2)){
    var Cantidadproducto =  $('#producto'+codigo1).val();
    var nuevaCP = parseInt(Cantidadproducto) + 1;
    $('#producto'+codigo1).val(parseInt(nuevaCP));
    agregarDescuento()
    sumarTotalPrecios()
    listarProductos()
}
```

hasta aquí estoy realizando un cambio en el valor mi input por lo tanto se debería ejecutar la siguiente función:

**Función**

```
$(".formularioVenta").on("change","input.nuevaCantidadProducto", function() {
    var precio = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".ingresoPrecio").children().children(".nuevoPrecioProducto");
    var PrecioFinal = $(this).val() * precio.attr("precioReal");
    precio.val(PrecioFinal);
    var nuevoStock = Number($(this).attr("stock")) - $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("nuevoStock",nuevoStock);

    if(Number($(this).val()) > Number($(this).attr("stock")) ){

        $(this).val(1);

        var PrecioFinal = $(this).val() * precio.attr("precioReal");

        precio.val(PrecioFinal);
        agregarDescuento()
        sumarTotalPrecios()
        alert("¡Sólo hay "+$(this).attr("stock")+" unidades!");

    }
    agregarDescuento()
    sumarTotalPrecios()
    listarProductos()
});
```

la función anterior solo se ejecuta cuando voy al input y yo algo el cambio manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El evento "change" basicamente depende del evento "blur" que basicamente es un evento que se lanza cuando se pierde el foco en un elemento,  cuando haces `$('#producto'+codigo1).val(parseInt(nuevaCP))` estas asignando el valor al campo, pero no hay ningun evento que se dispare, si te fijas, cuando cambias manualmente probablemente este haga el cambio al presionar Enter o salir del campo, ejecutando el evento "blur".

basicamente lo que puedes hacer es el change() en el codigo, creo deberia de ser suficiente.

```
$('#producto'+codigo1).val(parseInt(nuevaCP)).change()
```